# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.1-5326820

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting this error while running Android app in Android Studio version 3.4.1 : 
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.1-5326820.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.4.1-5326820/aapt2-3.4.1-5326820.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.4.1-5326820/aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :app